# File drag&drop, detect when dropped outside?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'd like to modify the default behavior of my browser when drag&drop-ing a file in my webapp (html5).
By default, if you drop a file outside a dropable box the browser tries to open it and quit the current page.

On gmail, this is desactivated!
Have you got an idea how this is done ?

I was thinking about the onbeforeunload event but it creates an alert so it's not the solution.

(I'm using [plupload](http://www.plupload.com/))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try this:

```
$(window).bind('drop', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
});
$(window).bind('dragover', function(event) {// the ondragover event needs to be canceled in Google Chrome and Safari to allow firing the ondrop event:
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're on the right track with onbeforeunload, however you might want to disable the alert with a preventdefaultbehavior. Let me know how that works...

Comment: Sorry this didn't work! Firefox and chrome ignore preventDefault() for this event. I found a solution which is quite ugly: when the uploader appears I add the three native events : dragover, dragenter and drop to every div containers.

Answer (score 0):

You should make the whole page expect a file drop and not accept it.